# Argument not getting passed into function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to simply pass a variable from a click event to an outside function. I keep getting my console.log string when testing for undefined.

Here is my click event.

```
        $("#previous, #next").click(function() {
        if ((this).id == 'next') {
            slideID++
        } else {
            slideID--
        }
        clearInterval($('#slides').data('interval'));
        $("ul.pagination li").removeClass("current");

        portfolioSwitch(slideID);
    });
```

I call the portfolioSwitch function with the argument of slideID. I have tested with my console to see if the slideID exists. It comes back with the id I want.

On my function I have this code.

```
if (portfolioSwitch.slideID === undefined) {
        console.log('Its undefined!');
}
```

It comes back as undefined still. So I did a console.log on the actual argument from the function.

```
console.log(portfolioSwitch.slideID);
```

It still is undefined. Why isn't it being passed?

Comment: What is `portfolioSwitch.slideID`? Let's see the `portfolioSwitch` function. In fact, let's see a [_testcase_](http://sscce.org).

Comment: It would just be `slideID` in the `portfolioSwitch` function, not `portfolioSwitch.slideID`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `console.log(portfolioSwitch.slideID);` use `console.log(slideID);`

Answer (score 0):

may be the variable portfolioSwitch.slideID is private?
inside the function

portfolioSwitch(slideID){
this.slideID = slideID; //?

}

//USE this to make public inside function.